# How to style a Google Doc using Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Currently, I have a web application that basically consists in a simple form. When I submit this form, I generate a document that I send to Google Drive. It works.

My problem is that I have no styling and I wonder how I can do that? I tried with HTML and CSS but if the HTML allows me to structure my document, the CSS does nothing.

So, how could I do that?

Comment: can u explain it little bit??HTML allows me to structure my document ,the CSS does nothing...

Comment: If you show us some sample code that you are currently using to talk to Google Drive, it will allow us to give you more specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're uploading an HTML file, with convert=true, to create a Google Doc. Any "attached" CSS file will be ignored. There is some embedded element styling that will be honoured by the conversion process. Perhaps the best approach would be to create a sample styled document manually, then export it as HTML to see how the styling works.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. Dumb of me not having thought about it earlier :) I'll keep you updated.