# How to get a nested html list into Drive/Google Docs using Google Drive Api v2?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

We have an application which gets an html document from our database and then the application inserts the file into Drive and converts the document to Google Docs format.

We are using Google Drive Api v2 (Files.insert and convert=true).

It's working quite well but one big question is how to get a nested list into Google Docs? When converting nested lists to Google Docs, it makes the tabulator working weird. Indentations are not working well. If I want to indent the first item, it goes to the left like it should'nt.

Our html document contains nested lists like this

```
 `<ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea
    <ul>
     <li>Black tea</li>
     <li>Green tea</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>`
```

We have been trying to add css-classes to our html, like "lst-kix-..", "c3"  like Google Docs is using (when loading the html content via Docs) but we are not able to get it work.

Eg. if I create an empty document with nested list in Google Docs and then I look the html code of it, there are only simple lists. Html code looks like:

```
 `<ul class="zz">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea
  </ul>
  <ul class=yy"> 
    <li>Black tea</li>
    <li>Green tea</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="xx">
    <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>`
```

but that's not making the html lists like we want (=nested lists).

Does someone have an idea how to do this?

Converting an html to "Word html" would be one solution if we knew how to use Google styles..maybe?

Comment: I have seen this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584845/how-to-style-a-google-doc-using-google-drive-api and tried to figure out how styling works. Almost everything else works, but not nested lists. I have no idea how to style lists.

Comment: And there is a link which tells something about this problem what I have: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/vvC8mqO7JmU